# Copy attachment from contact to opportunity

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to grab/copy an attachment(pdf) from a custom object called personal credit report to Opportunity page via Apex. Somebody has already done this or something similar?

Comment: Take a look at the `SObject.clone` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm). Also, please poke around the [help] and specifically read [ask]. Without an example to demonstrate what you have tried so far, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I am very new to SFSE. I will try to work out something and then come back with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your solution is going to be the `SObject.clone` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm). You will want to make sure you set `preserveId` to false. You may want to use a deep clone, depending on what further processing you want to do to the original record.

```
Attachment newRecord = initialAttachment.clone(
    /*preserveId*/ false,
    /*isDeepClone*/ true,
    /*preserveReadonlyTimestamps*/ false,
    /*preserveAutonumber*/ false
);
newRecord.ParentId = someOpportunity.Id;
```

Note that all the parameters above are optional. The defaults are all `false`, so if you don't want a deep clone, you can change that first line to:

```
Attachment newRecord = initialAttachment.clone();
```